# Add and Remove Friend Button

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

I am with some difficulties on create an Add Friend and Remove Friend button.
For example if the 'accepted' row in mysql of table friends_request is equals to 1 then it should appears the 'Remove Friend' button, otherwise it should appears the 'Add Friend' button.

Here is the code of the buttons I did, which is wrong.

```
<?php 

            $selfriendsBtn = "SELECT fr.username
               FROM (select from_username AS username
                     FROM friends_request
                     WHERE to_username = '".$_GET['u']."' AND accepted = 1
                     UNION ALL
                     SELECT to_username AS username
                     FROM friends_request
                     WHERE from_username = '".$_GET['u']."' AND accepted = 1) AS fr
               JOIN users AS u ON u.username = fr.username LIMIT 5";
            $resultfriend_add_rmv = $sql->query($selfriendsBtn);
            $rowAdd_RmvFriend = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultfriend_add_rmv);

            $accepted = $rowAdd_RmvFriend['accepted'];

            if($user != $_GET['u']) {
                if($accepted == 1) {            
            ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form action="profile.php?u=<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>&deleted=<?php echo $user; ?>" method="POST">
                                <input type="submit" name="rmvfriend" value="Remove Friend" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="profile.php?u=<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>&a=compose" method="POST">
                                <input type="submit" name="msg" value="Message" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php
                } else {
            ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <form action="profile.php?u=<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>&requested=<?php echo $user; ?>" method="POST">
                                <input type="submit" name="addfriend" value="Add Friend" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <form action="profile.php?u=<?php echo $_GET['u']; ?>&a=compose" method="POST">
                                <input type="submit" name="msg" value="Message" />
                            </form>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php 
                }
            }

            ?>
```

The SELECT tables I pick up from the **friends.php** page and implemented it on here.
I don't know why it's not working. Should I use loop or not? Well, in my opinion I think a loop it would work very well on this.

Comment: `"I think a loop it would work very well on this"` - Have you tried that then?  What makes you think that would be the solution?  When you debug this, how specifically is it failing?  At a quick glance the first thing I notice is that you seem to be trying to fetch a value from your database result which isn't selected in your query.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: @David the value I am fetching is on query, it's the "accepted = 1" and I didn't try the loop.

Comment: @NunixMonteiro: You're looking for the value "accepted": `$rowAdd_RmvFriend['accepted']`.  You're selecting the value "username": `SELECT fr.username`.  "username" and "accepted" are two different values.

Comment: @David I follow your instruction of the loop and it worked. Thank you so much. It was wrong of me to think it would not work. But it does. Thank you once again.

Comment: @David after all is not working very well instead appears just one button it duplicates it

Comment: @NunixMonteiro: You should really turn on error reporting, check error logs, and do some debugging here.  Even at least more clearly describe the nature of the problem.  "It's not working" doesn't tell us anything.  Based on the code shown so far, you are trying to read a value that isn't present in your database results.  So the attempt to read it will always be an error and always be false.  So the `if` statement will always have the same result.

Comment: @David:  it doesn't have any error_reporting on that. I turn to show all them and it didn't show in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a value that isn't present in the result set:

```
$accepted = $rowAdd_RmvFriend['accepted'];
```

The only value you select from the database is the username:

```
SELECT fr.username
FROM ...
```

So `$accepted` will never be equal to `1`.  Thus, this will always be false:

```
if ($accepted == 1)
```

So the `else` block (the "Add Friend" button) will always be shown.

You should also select the `accepted` value from your query so you can use it in your logic.  This is mostly a guess based on your query so far, but it looks like you'd need to add it in three places:

```
SELECT fr.username, fr.accepted -- here
FROM (select from_username AS username, accepted -- here
      FROM friends_request
      WHERE to_username = ? AND accepted = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT to_username AS username, accepted -- here
      FROM friends_request
...
```

Keep in mind that nobody here really knows your data, so you may need to tinker with the query a little bit in your database management tools to get it just right.

Comment: It appears this: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xamppnew\htdocs\codinglife\SocialNetwork_Tutorials\profile.php on line 47

line 47 is "`$rowAdd_RmvFriend = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultfriend_add_rmv);`"

Comment: @NunixMonteiro: That's a pretty important detail.  If you Google that error message, you'll find a commonly cited Stack Overflow question for it.

Comment: I found out a way to do it. I deleted all this and put it like this:
 `$selfriendsBtn = "SELECT id FROM friends_request 
   WHERE (from_username = '".$_GET['u']."' AND to_username = '$user') OR 
   (from_username = '$user' AND to_username = '".$_GET['u']."') AND accepted = 1";
   $resultFriendAR = $sql->query($selfriendsBtn);` 
------------------------------------------------
And it worked with the num_rows after it.